# BIND9 reverse lookup not working

Tags: linux, dns, bind9

I wanted to setup my own DNS on lan. I managed to get working forward lookup but for some unknown reason reverse lookup is not working.

downloaded bind9
`apt-get install bind9`

/etc/bind/named.conf.options

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        forwarders {
        // Google Public DNS
                8.8.8.8; // Use for Primary <-- modified
        //      8.8.4.4; // Use for Secondary
        };

        //========================================================================
        // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
        // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
        //========================================================================
        dnssec-validation auto;

        listen-on-v6 { any; };
        listen-on { 10.10.222.171; }; // <-- modified
};
```

added 1 forward 1 reverse zones
/etc/bind/named.conf.local

```
zone "kotylu.dev" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.kotylu.dev";
};

zone "222.10.10.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.10";
};
```

db.kotylu.dev

```
;
; BIND data file for kotylu.dev
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     kotylu.dev. root.kotylu.dev. (
                             16         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      kotylu.dev.
@       IN      A       10.10.222.171
@       IN      AAAA    ::1
gw      IN      A       10.10.222.1
desktop IN      A       10.10.222.201
tablet  IN      A       10.10.222.202
```

/etc/bind/db.10

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for 222.10.10
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     kotylu.dev. root.kotylu.dev. (
                             22         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      kotylu.dev.
171     IN      PTR     kotylu.dev.
1       IN      PTR     gw.kotylu.dev.
201     IN      PTR     desktop.kotylu.dev.
202     IN      PTR     tablet.kotylu.dev.
```

running `nslookup gw.kotylu.dev`:

```
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  fd33:330f:8aa::1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    gw.kotylu.dev
Address:  10.10.222.1
```

running `nslookup 10.10.222.1`:

```
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  fd33:330f:8aa::1

*** UnKnown can't find 10.10.222.1: Non-existent domain
Address:  10.10.222.1
```